# Exception Handling guideline- Python vs Java

Tags: java, python, exception

I am original Java developer, for me, checked Exception in Java is obviously/easy enough for me to decide to catch or throw it to the caller to handle later. Then it comes Python, there is no checked exception, so conceptually, nothing forces you to handle anything(In my experience, you don't even know what exceptions are potentially thrown without checking the document). I've been hearing quite a lot from Python guys that, in Python, sometimes you better just let it fail at runtime instead of trying to handle the exceptions.

Can someone give me some pointers regarding to:

1. what's the guideline/best practice for Python Exception Handling?
2. what's the difference between Java and Python in this regard?

Comment: Not only nothing forces you to handle anything, but finding documentation on what exceptions are thrown when is a royal PITA :/

Comment: @fge yes, exactly, it is quite annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I can try and give an answer which I'll keep as neutral as it can be... (note: I have done Python professionally for a few months, but I am far from mastering the language in its entirety)

1. The guidelines are "free"; if you come from a Java background, you will certainly spend more time than most Python devs out there looking for documentation on what is thrown when, and have more `try`/`except`/`finally` than what is found in regular python code. In other words: do what suits you.
2. Apart from the fact that they can be thrown anywhere, at any moment, Python has multi-exception catch (only available in Java since 7), `with` (somewhat equivalent to Java 7's try-with-resources), you can have more than one `except` block (like Java can `catch` more than once), etc. Additionally, there are no real conventions that I know of on how exceptions should be named, so don't be fooled if you see `SomeError`, it may well be what a Java dev regards as a "checked exception" and not an `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python dev, but I've done a quite bit of work in C#, which also doesn't have checked exceptions. Being a Java coder that took some getting used to. I personally still think checked exceptions are a nice feature, but opinions differ wildly (as you can see in some of the responses here).

There are quite a few articles online on why checked exceptions are(n't) a good idea (see [this blog](http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions) for one such opinion).

But regardless of your preference: the rule of thumb in Python and C# is to do essentially what you're already doing - test runs and reading the docs.

What I'd typically do in C# is have a 'catch-all' exception handler at the root of my program that makes sure any error is reported and the program exits cleanly, and then deeper in my code have more specific exception handlers for "known specific errors". So actually, not so different from how you'd work in Java, just a little more work to figure out where to put your specific handlers.

Comment: @fge, in fact, as far as I know, they're very much a Java-specific feature.

Comment: Well, for starters it has your *opinions* in it.

Answer (score -4):

1. Best practice is to handle appropriate exceptions in the appropriate place. Only you, as developer, can decide which part of your code should catch exceptions. This should become apparent with decent unit testing. If you have unhandled exceptions, they will show up.
2. You already described the differences. At a more fundamental level, Java's designers think they know better than you how you should code, and they'll force you to write lots of it. Python, by contrast, assumes that you are an adult, and that you know what you want to do. This means that you can shoot yourself in the foot if you insist on so doing.

Comment: The second point is a personal opinion and by no means objective.

Comment: The difference is not about "Java's designer thinking they know better". Checked exceptions are simply a language feature that can inform you as a coder at *compile time*, rather than at runtime, that a problem might occur. It's fine if you don't like that feature, but honestly, lose the attitude.

Comment: I'd appreciate the answer from the neutral/middle zone between Java and Python.

Comment: @Shengjie What is this imaginary neutral middle zone?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I'm sorry, but the language designers have explicitly stated that the purpose of Java is to prevent programmers from making what they consider to be mistakes.

Comment: @Marcin and how does that make it a child's language? Crap code in Java exists nevertheless, examples are countless if you browse questions here on SO. They have made design choices, some of them being arguable, but this is the same for all languages; there is no end to this. For instance I dislike the fact that Python has no instance variable encapsulation, does that make me say that Python sucks? No. It is just a design decision I disagree with, that does not make Python a bad language.

Comment: @fge You're putting words in my mouth, and I will not respond to such strawmen. To address your specific example, you dislike that python lacks a feature which java has, which specifically exists with the rationale that it prevents mistakes. This illustrates the distinction between java and python, as I have described it above.

Comment: @Marcin I'm sorry but no. You say that "Java's designers think they know better than you", I am sorry but that is as one-sided a statement as a statement can be. You don't like it, OK. Generalizing your dislike to what Java language designers thought stems from _your_ personal point of view _only_.

Comment: @fge I'm not sure what you're claiming here, or how it relates to what I have said. I've read the Java designers explicitly state that one of the purposes of Java is to prevent programmer errors by essentially forcing programmers to do things in the "right" way. No, I don't have a source, and I'm not going to spend more time tracking one down for you. I'm not sure why you're so offended to be confronted with the core principle of your favourite language.

Comment: @Marcin as always, such statements should be read with a grain of salt. The "right" way? No one knows what it is, because such a definition is, by nature, subjective. I just happen to like Java more than Python, while deeply regretting some of their decisions (no unsigned types being one of them), but I don't go as far as to pretend that "Java is a child's language" or "Python has no encapsulation, it sucks". It is just that I like Java's design better on the whole. I make no personal, opinionated statement about what language is the best. There isn't one.

Comment: @fge Again, you're putting words in my mouth. You made those statements, not me. Go argue with yourself.

Comment: @Marcin fine, prove it yourself and delete that non constructive answer then ;)

Comment: @fge What would that prove? Once again, you are arguing against a voice in your head. Your quotations are not taken from me, but rather entirely fabricated by you.

Comment: @Marcin the language designers adding a feature because they think it will help prevent coders making mistakes is not the same as "they think they know better and will force you to write lots of code". Apart from anything else, nobody _forces_ you to use checked exceptions (or indeed to catch/handle them properly). It just gives you the means to do so _if you want to_. I'll grant you that you can't completely ignore them but just adding a throws clause is hardly "forcing you to write lots of code".

Comment: @JeenBroekstra "nobody forces you to use checked exceptions" That's only true in the sense that nobody forces you to use the standard library. "just adding a throws clause is hardly forcing you to write lots of code" Until you have to add it to every function that potentially calls that function directly or indirectly. But, that's just a symptom of the larger problem that Java has lots of features that demand redundant code.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I'm missing your point? Maybe you should actually articulate it.