# How can I call exceptions or functions instantaneously in Python program execution?

Tags: python, automation

I have an application which is automated through Python script. The application may hang or crash anytime unknowingly. Hence I need to write an exception or function to handle the same.

I have to call this exception or function as if it is running in background and should be revoked whenever crash or hang happens.

For ex:
consider my python script is doing an automation on an application. It is doing following...

1. Open the Application
2. Browse over a icon
3. Clicks on the icon
4. Select some file
5. Upload that file
6. Close the Application

During any of these steps, the crash or hang may occur in the application and I have a different "function/ method" for each of the steps. How to invoke the exception at every steps.

I know it is easy to do in java like:
public void openApp() throws CrashException, ErrorException {

But I don't know how to do the same in python. 
Please help me with the same.

Comment: Python doesn't require you to declare what exceptions a function throws, and even in Java, just declaring that your function `throws` whatever exceptions won't handle the exceptions or do anything about hangs.

Answer (score 0):

1)You can see here the [Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) in python.

2)[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158233/exception-handling-guideline-python-vs-java) examines the differences between python and java regarding exception handling.

3)For a simple exception handling in python taken from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html):

```
 def divide(x, y):
     try:
        result = x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print "division by zero!"
    else:
        print "result is", result
    finally:
        print "executing finally clause"
```

Comment: I am sorry, I think I failed to clearly tell my problem here. My requirement is like this...

I have several methods(functions) written to execute. I need to imply the same crashexception on all the methods. calling the exception after each and every operation/line in each and every functions is not a good idea, therefore I need an alternative way of handling the same situation. The exception needs to invoked wherever applicable. I need the exception to be running in the background of each methods.

Comment: @BharathKashyap like what?