# InputStream's FileInputStream in Java

Tags: java, file, class, input, program-entry-point

Is this a correct way to open a "mat1.txt" file, because eclipse IDE is giving error?

```
InputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\eclipse-workspace\\edu\\iitd\\col1062020\\mat1.txt");
```

Error:

> Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

From the error, it is not able to locate the file but I have placed it in the path as provided. (see below)

[image: File location]

Is it due to access permissions in C drive?

Comment: `new FileInputStream` **opens** the file, and that can throw an `IOException` such as `FileNotFoundException`. Solution `try { .... } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace()); }`

Comment: thank after doing that it is not showing the error. but can you tell why it showed the error on not doing exception handling? in other languages like python, it is not the case as the error is showed only when it is not able to access the code. in python if it can access the file it doesn't show any error even if we hadn't done any exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
InputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\eclipse-workspace\\edu\\iitd\\col1062020\\mat1.txt");
```

You should wrap your file access with try catch! The following try catch construct uses also the auto close feature! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

```
    try (InputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\eclipse-workspace\\edu\\iitd\\col1062020\\mat1.txt")) {
        // consume your InputStream
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you wrote `eclipseworkspace` but in the path there is a minus sign: `eclipse-workspace`.

Comment: actually i wrote eclipse-workspace in the my code. it must be something else

Comment: Okay, so if you wrote the correct path, the fault should be of the missing try/catch block. Just add it as CodingSamples has suggested in the other answer :)

Comment: thank. and after doing that it is not showing the error. but can you tell why it showed the error on not doing exception handling? in other languages like python, it is not the case as the error is showed only when it is not able to access the code. in python if it can access the file it doesn't show any error even if we hadn't done any exception handling.

Comment: Probably the path was wrong, link in your first post ... That's what the exception FileNotFoundException means... In java you have to handle Exceptions (except RuntimeException)

Comment: The handling exception of Java is actually a powerful mechanism: you can prevent the program from chrashing, and you can add descriptive messages that can be useful for the user. If you want to know something more about this topic, I suggest you to give a look to [this](https://stackify.com/specify-handle-exceptions-java/) link. And if you want to know some best practices for exception handling in Java, you can check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/9-best-practices-to-handle-exceptions-in-java) link as well :)

Comment: Also, to clarify the differences between Java and Python, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158233/exception-handling-guideline-python-vs-java) question, it's made from a Java guy who is learning Python. It's interesting and helpful, because he has your opposite point of view.